# Choosing folder to run jasmine from via npm

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to run jasmine from an subfolder rather than from the root of my project I tried running this `jasmine test/jasmine/` but it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do this via the `jasmine` command or do I need to use it as a library?

**update**:

Currently running it (via package.json) like this (working):

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run jasmine",
    "jasmine": "cd test/jasmine/ && jasmine"
  }
```

Comment: Don't exactly understand your question, but did you look at jasmine.json

Comment: @dzm so say I'm in `/my-project` and I'm trying to access the test files that are in `/my-project/test/jasmine`. What's the proper command to run that? Currently I'm running it via `cd test/jasmine && jasmine` in my `package.json` it seems to work but not sure if this is right.

Comment: you should be able to do `jasmine test/jasmine/**/*.spec.js`

Comment: @dzm what if I want to run multiple specs? This only runs a specific file

Comment: No this searches all directories within `test/jasmine` and all files that match `*.spec.js`

Comment: @dzm it seems to run but it does seem to get some errors related to the jasmine examples, maybe because of its relative path